# JMeter execution

Tags: java, jmeter

I am trying to execute a simple script in my laptop.But I get the below message and the script doesn't execute. Thread loop count is set to 3, tried adding header manager as well but no luck. 
As I want to see the execution I put in GUI mode but the request doesn't hit. I get the below log only with info and no error.

```
2015/05/31 00:41:23 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Running the test! 
2015/05/31 00:41:23 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.SampleEvent: List of sample_variables: [] 
2015/05/31 00:41:23 INFO  - jmeter.gui.util.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(true,*local*) 
2015/05/31 00:41:23 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting ThreadGroup: 1 : Thread Group 
2015/05/31 00:41:23 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting 1 threads for group Thread Group. 
2015/05/31 00:41:23 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Thread will continue on error 
2015/05/31 00:41:23 INFO  - jmeter.threads.ThreadGroup: Starting thread group number 1 threads 1 ramp-up 0 perThread 0.0 delayedStart=false 
2015/05/31 00:41:23 INFO  - jmeter.threads.ThreadGroup: Started thread group number 1 
2015/05/31 00:41:23 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: All thread groups have been started 
2015/05/31 00:41:23 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-1 
2015/05/31 00:41:23 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread is done: Thread Group 1-1 
2015/05/31 00:41:23 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Thread Group 1-1 
2015/05/31 00:41:23 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Notifying test listeners of end of test 
2015/05/31 00:41:23 INFO  - jmeter.gui.util.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(false,*local*)
```

Comment: I tried printing SOP in beanshell looks like its working. Issue is only with hitting request

Comment: At least I need more infos to help with your problem. Can you share screenshots, configuration or even your whole test script?

Comment: yes,it will better to configure view result tree. Hope it will will help you to find the cause.

Comment: Its working now....guess it was problem with my system...Thank you for all help

Answer (score 0):

Looking into log file script finishes normally. The best way to visualise request and response details is using [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener, this way you will be able to tell what exactly going on. The listener is also handy for debugging regular expressions, CSS and XPath queries, and checking variables and properties values in combination with [Debug Sampler](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script)

You can also configure JMeter to make logging more verbose. Add `log_level.jmeter=INFO` line to *user.properties* file (it it located in /bin folder of your JMeter installation), restart JMeter and inspect *jmeter.log* file for anything looking suspicious.

Once you figured out and fixed the cause it is highly recommended to revert the changes back, to wit:

- Disable or delete View Results Tree listener (as well as any other listeners)
- Restore logging level to "INFO" as in case of massive load disk IO usage by logging system will be immense and it may ruin your test